# Is there any Facebook friends network/graph downloader program that still works?

Tags: facebook

I'd like to download my network of Facebook friends as a graph/network for a university project. Nodes are my friends and the edges represent friendships between my friends.

[image: This is my FB friends network from 2014]

I used the following application so far:

- Netvizz (you can still download the Facebook networks of groups, pages, but the friends network function is banned)
- NameGenWeb (same situation as above)
- NodeXL with Social Network Importer (same situation as above)

I need all the information related to the nodes/edges structure of the friendship graph to calculate page rank, closeness and other metrics.

Do you know any alternative application for my purpose that still works (not banned by FB)?

Comment: It seems to be possible to crawl friendship network from HTML: https://linkurio.us/how-to-visualize-your-facebook-network/. (But I haven't tried it yet, so I cannot guarantee it works)

Comment: Try out this Chrome Webbrowser extension to do that: http://lostcircles.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no. Friendship connections have been removed from the API on April 30 and are no longer available even with any extended permissions. The only way to get that data would be to have every friend install an app and then triangulate friend connections; or work at Facebook.

Comment: It's too bad. I hope one day it'll be available again.

Comment: well, can we scrape via web browsers? At least for friends interact with friends?